# Is this particular subset of $L^{1}([0,1])$ a weakly compact set?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, weak-topology

I was wondering if this set
$$A_{3}=\bigl\{ u \in L^{1}([0,1]): \lvert\lvert u \rvert\rvert_{L^{1}([0,1])} \leq 1 \quad \int_{0}^{1}\frac{u(x)}{sin(x-\theta)} dx \leq1  \quad \forall \theta \in (0,\pi)\bigr\},$$
is weakly compact.

Comment: How do you interpret $\int_0^1 \frac{u(x)}{\sin(x-\theta)}\mathrm{d}x\leq 1$ condition?

Comment: @Jakobian The condition states that a family of integrals depending upon $\theta$ have to be less than $1$, but I would not know how to give an intuitive interpretation of this condition.

Comment: Does this mean this function is assumed to be absolutely integrable for all $\theta$ as well?

Comment: @Jakobian yes it does, because the integral it's the Lebesgue integral and not the Riemannian integral.

Comment: Can you give an example of a function from your set that is not identically zero?

Comment: @Jake28 No I cannot, I can only give an example of a sequence of functions $u_{n}$ with $\lvert \lvert u_{n} \rvert \rvert_{L^{1}([0,1])} \leq 1,$ and such that $$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{u_{n}(x)}{\sin(x-\theta_{0})}\, dx \leq 1 $$, where $\theta_{0}$ is a fixed element of $(0,\pi)$. That sequence is $$u_{n}(x)=n \cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x) \cdot \sin(x-\theta_{0}).$$

Comment: I suggest you to show that your set contains only the zero function, in which case the statement is trivially true.

Comment: @Jake28 I will thought about that, I was thinking about a proof by absurd. If there was a function $u \ne 0$ in $A_3$, then without loss of generality I could suppose it is continuous. The continuity will imply the existence of an open interval in which $u$ does not assume the value zero, from there I hope to use the fact that $u\in A_3$.